# Template meta programming integral specialization

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I'm making a simple `max` function to experiment with template metaprogramming in C++.  I expect to see "integral" to display when I call the function with an int but it isn't and I don't know why:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class...   > struct make_void { typedef void type; };
template<class... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

#include <type_traits>

template < class T, class = void_t < typename std::is_integral<T>::value > >
    T max(T x, T y) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

template<class T, class = void>
    T max(const T& x, const T& y) {
    std::cout << "class" << std::endl;
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

int main() {
    int x = 5,y = 3;
    std::cout << "int: ";
    max(x,y);
    struct str{bool operator>(const str&other)const{return true;}} a, b;
    std::cout << "blank struct: ";
    max(a,b);
}
```

In both cases it prints out class which worries me since I thought that SFINAE would select the better option more often.  I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: You don't have any SFINAE here?

Comment: `std::is_integral<T>::value` is not a `type`.

Comment: First, get rid of `typename`. Next, `void_t` isn't the tool to use here in this context. Use `std::enable_if_t`. You also need a negation of the condition (`!is_integral`) in the second overload. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2bdcf651c1e7604c

Comment: [OT]: standard uses `operator <` instead of `operator >`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::is_integral<T>::value` is not a type, so

```
template < class T, class = void_t<typename std::is_integral<T>::value>>
T max(T x, T y)
```

is still rejected with SFINAE.

You may use `std::enable_if_t`

```
template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value, T> max(const T& x, const T& y) {
    std::cout << "integral" << std::endl;
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral<T>::value, T> max(const T& x, const T& y) {
    std::cout << "class" << std::endl;
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/757b8cb36e85fd93)

Comment: How is it more specialized?

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to make it work as intended?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Indeed, it is not more specialized. Answer rewritten.

Comment: @Czipperz: possible implementation with Demo added.

Comment: @Czipperz: If you can't use C++14 and `std::enable_if_t<Cond, T>` you may replace it by `typename std::enable_if<Cond, T>::type`.

Comment: @Jarod42 yea I submitted an edit for that which I guess got rejected